# Highstock dataGrouping option

Tags: highcharts

I have gone through the highstock datagrouping documenation(https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping), But little unclear about this data grouping option, Things I have noticed is, Data grouping is enabled by default in highstock, I n which we can force the datagrouping by giving custom datagrouping option through **units**  option in datagrouping, The doubt I got is which is the default data grouping(default unit option) in highstock, another one is do we need to tell the datagrouping units for each time interval by which we are gonna show in chart(eg, if the datarange chosen is one month the grouping should by 1 day, If the daterange chosen is one day means the datagrouping units should be by hour),

```
units: [[
    'millisecond', // unit name
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500] // allowed multiples
], [
    'second',
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
], [
    'minute',
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
], [
    'hour',
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
], [
    'day',
    [1]
], [
    'week',
    [1]
], [
    'month',
    [1, 3, 6]
], [
    'year',
    null
]]
```

Do we need to specify each unit or do we need to change the units dynamically based on the daterange chosen?

This is what I have done, The based on the daterange the user chosen the grouping units should be changed, Do we need to specify the units based on the daterange chosen and what the units array specifies (Is Giving only one unit as option to the grouping is the functionality, Or the units array options can be chosen based on the timestamps)

```
Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {

      chart: {
        zoomType: false
      },

      legend: {
        enabled: true
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 0,
        y: -20
      },

      navigator: {
        enabled: false
      },

      rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
      },
    
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
      },

      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day:"%b %e"
        }
      },

      yAxis: {
        opposite : false
      },
     series: [{
       data: data ,
    marker: {
      enabled: true
    },
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      approximation: "sum"
    }
  }]
```

**EDIT**
While forced option is set to false
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> which is the default data grouping(default unit option) in highstock

There's a little flaw in the **API** (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping.units) in `units` section. First it says that it defaults to:

```
units: [[
    'millisecond', // unit name
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500] // allowed multiples
], [
    'second',
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
], [
    'minute',
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
], [
    'hour',
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
], [
    'day',
    [1]
], [
    'week',
    [1]
], [
    'month',
    [1, 3, 6]
], [
    'year',
    null
]]
```

and after that "Defaults to `undefined`." line appears. The first one is correct.

Highcharts automatically finds the best grouping unit from `units` array. So, in other words: `units` specifies which groupings can be applied **if** Highcharts decides that applying data grouping is a good idea.

Enable `dataGrouping.forced` and use only one key-value pair in `units` array if you want to make sure that this grouping will be used no matter what e.g.:

```
units: [[
    'hour',
    [3]
] // Data will always be grouped into 3 hours periods
```

These're just general rules - they should be enough to use data grouping successfully.

Comment: I have added an image in which i have commented out the datagrouping forced option(
`dataGrouping: {
#          forced: true,
#          approximation: "sum",
#          units: units
        }` ),
 But the highstock doesn't look like grouping

Comment: Why did you commented out `dataGrouping.forced`? It should be set to true and not commented out.

Comment: Even when the the forced option set to true and I added default units array it doesn't seems like grouping with appropriate grouping in the units array `dataGrouping: {
          forced: true,
          approximation: "sum",
          units: [[ 'millisecond',[1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500]], ['second',[1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]], ['minute',[1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]], ['hour',[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]], ['day',[1]
], ['week', [1]], ['month',[1, 3, 6]], ['year',null ]]`

Comment: Please provide a live demo (jsfiddle ideally) that recreates the problem.